# Fulltext search doesn't work after sometime and require rebuilding

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table which we rebuild everyday in the morning. The fulltext query runs successfully on that table after rebuilding. But after some time if I run the same query, I get no result. And again after rebuilding query works. Why does it again require rebuild? We only make changes to the table during morning before rebuild.

Query :

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [PSM_HU3] REBUILD 
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.tblPsmSucheSuchbegriff START FULL POPULATION
```

search query :

```
select count(*) from containstable(tblPsmSucheSuchbegriff, PsmSucheSuchbegriffVolltext,'iphone',10)
```

Comment: So what is your query?

Comment: i rebuild only once in morning. fulltext query run successfully at that time. but after some time it doesn't give any results. why?

Comment: Show your query to us. If you dont provide the query, we can give any reason but this may not your case.

Comment: Rebuild query: ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [PSM_HU3] REBUILD
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.tblPsmSucheSuchbegriff START FULL POPULATION and search query : select count(*) from containstable(tblPsmSucheSuchbegriff, PsmSucheSuchbegriffVolltext,'iphone',10)